# Custom type mapping for 'xxx.DataAccess.UDT_Table_Numbers' is not specified or is invalid

Tags: c#

I have a puzzle problem. Sometimes our program occurs "Custom type mapping for 'xxx.DataAccess.UDT_Table_Numbers' is not specified or is invalid." exception. After I restart IIS server, it is work. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Relation code as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

using OMS.BusinessEntity.ORDValid;
using OMS.Utilities.DBUtility;
using OMS.Utilities.Common;


namespace OMS.ORDValid.DataAccess
{
public class ExceptionHandlingDAO
{
    public string AcceptOrder(string UserID, string Customer, string OrderNo, string Exflag, string LineString, string PriorityFlag, 
                                            List<string> LstPrice)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(OracleHelper.Wistron_WOMS_ConnStr);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

        try
        {
            ....
            string ProcedureName = "PROC_ACCEPTORDER";

            OracleParameter[] parmArray = {
                new OracleParameter("v_rodno", OracleDbType.Varchar2),
                new OracleParameter("v_customer", OracleDbType.Varchar2),
                new OracleParameter("v_exflag", OracleDbType.Varchar2),
                new OracleParameter("v_userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2), 
                new OracleParameter("v_highPriority", OracleDbType.Varchar2),
                new OracleParameter("v_lineString", OracleDbType.Varchar2),
                new OracleParameter("v_PriceList", OracleDbType.Object),
                new OracleParameter("v_result", OracleDbType.Varchar2),
            };

            parmArray[0].Value = OrderNo;
            parmArray[1].Value = Customer;
            parmArray[2].Value = Exflag;
            parmArray[3].Value = UserID;
            parmArray[4].Value = PriorityFlag;
            parmArray[5].Value = LineString;

            parmArray[6].UdtTypeName = "OMS.EXCEPTION_REASON";
            parmArray[6].Value = new UDT_Table_Numbers { Value = LstPrice.ToArray() }; 
            parmArray[7].Size = 5000;   

            parmArray[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parmArray[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parmArray[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parmArray[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parmArray[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parmArray[5].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parmArray[6].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parmArray[7].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            foreach (OracleParameter parm in parmArray)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
            }

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = ProcedureName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string temp = cmd.Parameters["v_result"].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            return temp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            ...
        }
    }

}

public class UDT_Table_Numbers : TableTemplate<string>
{
    // Inherited from TableTemplate   
}

// Factory to create an object for the above class   
[OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("OMS.EXCEPTION_REASON")]
public class StringTableFactory : TableFactoryTemplate<UDT_Table_Numbers>
{
    public override System.Array CreateStatusArray(int length)
    {
        OracleUdtStatus[] udtStatus = new OracleUdtStatus[length];
        return udtStatus;
    }
}


public class TableTemplate<Type> : IOracleCustomType
{
    [OracleArrayMappingAttribute()]
    public virtual Type[] Value { get; set; }

    public virtual void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, System.IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        if (this.Value != null)
        {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, 0, this.Value);
        }
    }

    public virtual void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, System.IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        this.Value = ((Type[])(OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, 0)));
    }
}

public class TableFactoryTemplate<T> : IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory where T : IOracleCustomType, new()
{
    public virtual IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        return obj;
    }

    public virtual System.Array CreateArray(int length)
    {
        System.Type type = typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].PropertyType.GetElementType();
        return Array.CreateInstance(type, length);
    }

    public virtual System.Array CreateStatusArray(int length)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class NullableAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to have using blocks for your Connection and Command objects to dispose them properly. The exception handling removes all information that might have been present in the original exception. If that is not your intent, try passing your exception as inner exception, so it's still accessible to interested parties later.

Comment: Can you please post full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The detail stack trace as below:
---- Stack Trace ----
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(reqMsg As IMessage, retMsg As IMessage)
       (unknown file): N 4729427
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(msgData As MessageData&, type As Int32)
       (unknown file): N 01725
   OMS.ORDValid.ORDValidServiceRef.ORDValidServiceContract.BatchUpdateExcptHandling(request As BatchUpdateExcptHandlingRequest)
       (unknown file): N 00000
   OMS.ORDValid.ORDValidServiceRef.ORDValidServiceContractClient.BatchUpdateExcptHandling(ActionType As String, CustomerString As String, ORDExceptionHDInfo As List`1, UserID As String, Result As String&)
       Reference.cs: line 2532, col 13, IL 0035
   OMS.ORDValid.Views.ExceptionHandlingDefaultPresenter.BatchExceptHandle(list As List`1)
       ExceptionHandlingDefaultPresenter.cs: line 0250, col 09, IL 0136
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(eventArgument As String)
       (unknown file): N 00154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint As Boolean, includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint As Boolean)
       (unknown file): N 03707

Exception Type:        System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
Exception Message:     Custom type mapping for 'xxx.DataAccess.UDT_Table_Numbers' is not specified or is invalid.
Exception Source:      mscorlib